# Using IF statement to test the ON/OFF setting of iOS Switch Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement, controls

I am new to Objective-C, but use JavaScript and a lot of VB.NET and some C for firmware development.  I am writing beginner level Apps and in this case, have a SWITCH control on my View.  I want to know how to use an IF statement to test it's ON/OFF state.  Sample code is best as I am legally blind and have difficulty reading lots of text online.

Same issue for the Stepper control (The control with the +/_ buttons used to increment / decrement values.)

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly you want to archive with the stepper. there is no `on` state.

Answer (score 5):

UISwitch does have a property `on` (check the docu here: [UISwitch class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006784-CH3-SW5)) so check the property (note that the getter is named differently (`isOn`)):

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on
```

So one would check the switch like this:

```
if ([switch isOn])
{}
else
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

first add a target to the switch for event `UIControlEventValueChanged` after adding the switch to your view,  then use the switch's property to determine its state,

```
 [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void) switchToggled:(id)sender {
        UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
        if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
            NSLog(@"its on!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"its off!");
        }
    }
```